# Parse error : "Failed to initialize mongo connection

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

We have a big emergency issue here. All the connection with Parse's servers are down on this application, with the error : "Failed to initialize mongo connection".

Am I the only one with this issue ?

Any news about this ?!

[Error in Chrome console capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcY6b.png)

Comment: Check their online status. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381992/how-to-counter-the-down-status-of-your-database-provider-parse-com for details.